# How to get and add Core Table data in magento2

Tags: database, model, customer-group, service-contract

I need to get and add a new Core table data. So, I tried based on get custom table data way(Model, ResourceModel) but it's not working for me.

For example I need to collect `customer_group` data

What I did: (Using **Api**)

```
      <?php
        namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Index;
        use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart as CustomerCart;
        use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface;
        use Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface;

        class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
        {

            protected  $_groupDataFactory;

            protected $dataObjectProcessor;

            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
                Session $csession,
                \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
                \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
                GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
                GroupInterfaceFactory $groupDataFactory,
                \Magento\Framework\Reflection\DataObjectProcessor $dataObjectProcessor

            )
            {
                $this->dataObjectProcessor = $dataObjectProcessor;
                parent::__construct($context,$groupRepository,
                    $groupDataFactory);
            }

            public function execute()
            {

                        try
                        {
                         $customerGroup = $this->_groupDataFactory->create();
                         $this->_logger->addDebug(serialize($customerGroup));


                        }
                        catch (\Exception $e)
                        {
                           // echo $e;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Model Way:

```
           protected $_groupFactory;

            public function __construct(
                \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
                \Magento\Customer\Model\Group $groupFactory

            )
            {
                parent::__construct($context);
                $this->_groupFactory=$groupFactory;
            }

            public function getTableData()
            {

                $result=$this->_groupFactory->create()->getCollection();

                var_dump($result);

            }
```

Both above way not working for me , Suggest me How to get and add a data to  core table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You injected the right class which is `Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface` but you didn't use it.

To get the list of customer groups you can call:

```
$this->groupRepository->getList();
```

PS: don't forget to assign this class to a class variable of yours such as `protected $groupRepository` if you want this code to work

To create new customer groups you first need to use `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterfaceFactory` to create the customer group:

```
$customerGroup = $this->groupDataFactory->create();
$customerGroup->setCode('customer_group_custom_code');
$customerGroup->setTaxClassId($taxClassId);
```

NB: please replace the code and tax class id with what you need

And then you can save it using the group repository:

```
$this->groupRepository->save($customerGroup);
```

Comment: ok, how to add a new value to that group

Comment: @Rajkumar.E see my edit